# Linked list insertion issue using function call

Tags: c

When we insert an element in a link list with the help of function call , why is it necessary to pass the reference of head instead of passing directly head for example...we use  void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data) instead of void push(struct node* head, int new_data)..where push is function to insert a element..?

Comment: Not sure of the reference, I'm assuming cause the `head` itself needs to be updated. Need entire code to give a definite answer

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough information on your push function to determine exactly why the function argument is like that (i.e. is it inserting an element at the end, or at the beginning?)

One of the main reasons to pass a pointer to a pointer is if the head pointer changes and you wish to keep the change after the function call.

There are two possibilities  I can think of as to why the insertion function has that argument structure.

If your push function is inserting at the end of the list, giving the insertion function an empty list (a null pointer in this case) the pointer to the head would change from a null pointer to the address of the single element inserted which is now the head.

If your push function is inserting at the head each time then the address of the head node is constantly changing.

For example in the following linked list the head pointer points to the node containing 1:

`1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4`

After pushing the data element 5 to the front the linked list representation would look like the following:

`5 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4`

So 5 is now where the head pointer should point to. However if the push function had the argument structure of `void push(struct node *head_ref, int new_data)` then the head_ref would still be pointing to the node containing 1 after exiting the function. However with `void push(struct node **head_ref, int new_data)` the changes to the location of the current `header_ref` is stored in the pointer to it.